# XPath Select all elements name of which NOT starts with Capital letter

Tags: xpath, xsd, startswith

I Have Schema Name.xsd, it's part of it,need help in framing the query in XPath that

```
    <xsd:complexType name="GetWalletItemBO">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="paymentOptionId">
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

my basic query is like  `//*[starts-with(name(),'**here I need to put my condition**')]`
I have to check that `xsd:complexType name` starts with Capital letter `GetWalletItemBO` and not like `getWalletItemBO` , and on the same way to check that `<xsd:element name=` starts with small letter `paymentOptionId` not like `PaymentOptionId` . **So I try find all elements that HAVE BAD input, don't appropriate to my conditions , that's starts with small letter in xsd:complexType name= ,and with Capital letter in xsd:element name= **.

Comment: What do you like to check? The schema or the xml? The question sounds like the name attribute in schema. But  your `starts-with(name(),` looks like the element name in XML. But any way have a look to `translate()` to create lower case. If lower case names are same but original name not you may have found an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `name()` but `local-name()` to get the name without namespace identifier. Then, split off the first letter and see if it is not contained in the capital letters:

```
//*[not(contains('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', substring(local-name(.), 1, 1)))]
```

Comment: It's nice advice!!! I changed my name of **xsd:complexType** but when I used that I got every inside Nodes include like **xsd:element** and others, not ONLY **xsd:complexType** that changed. How can I include only it ?

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, you do not want to return the whole subtree but only an empty result element. This is not possible with XPath, you cannot construct elements or modify subtrees. Use XQuery or XSLT.

Comment: Not exactly, It query return not only my result ,it returns every nodes, include sub nodes , how can I change that query for only **xsd:complexType** I tried to use /ancestor::* , but it's not really work

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
//xs:complexType[matches(@name, '$\P{Lu}')]
```

Comment: It's would be good , but inside name it's can be Capital letter, i check it with this query ` //xsd:complexType[matches(@name, '[a-z]')]`

Comment: Your query will match any complexType whose name contains a lower-case character, which isn't what you asked for.